# コインハイブでハッシュを計算している部分を特定して変更したい

Tags: javascript, ハッシュ

webサイトのhtmlに

```
<script src="https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('hogesitekey', {throttle: 0.3});

    // Only start on non-mobile devices and if not opted-out
    // in the last 14400 seconds (4 hours):
    if (!miner.isMobile() && !miner.didOptOut(14400)) {
        miner.start();
    }
<script>
```

と追加してみたところ jsファイル
https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js

が読みこまれてPCが重くなりcoinhiveがマイニングしていることを確認できたのですが

実際にハッシュを計算しているcryptnightのアルゴリズムは
coinhiveサーバーから読み込まれたjsファイルのどこに含まれているのでしょうか

純粋にhashを計算しているjsコード部分を特定して

そのハッシュ計算部分をブラウザとは違うソフトで計算したいのです

普段ならcoinhveから送られてきたjsがクライアント
のブラウザでハッシュ計算してcoinhiveのサーバーに送るという処理をしていると思いますが

coinhiveのjsを改造してcoinhiveのハッシュ計算部分だけを取り出してほかのソフトで計算したハッシュ計算結果をcoinhiveのjsの変数に代入していつも通りcoinhive jsがサーバーに結果を送るということがしたいです

要は純粋なハッシュ計算のソースコードを
バブルソートのコード見たく取り出したいのです

https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js
から

```
var a = [1,3,10,2,8];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

    for(var j = a.length-1; j>i ; j-- ){

        if(a[j]<a[j-1]){
            var tmp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] =tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

見たくハッシュ計算コードを抽出して
別のソフトに手渡しして計算して結果ををcoinhiveのjsにもどすみたいにです

このソフトはこの方法でしか実行できないがとてつもない処理能力をもつものと考えてください

Comment: わかりやすく例えると学校(coinhiveサーバ)からもらった数学宿題(coinhiveが渡すて来たjsファイル)ドリルから問題文(ハッシュ計算アルゴリズム)だけをほかの紙に書き写して　紙を数学者のパパ(超速ソフト)に渡して解かせて　パパ(超速ソフト)の出した答え(hash計算結果)を宿題のドリルに書きうつして学校(coinhiveサーバ)に提出するといった感じです

Comment: ちなみに、Moneroを効率よく採掘するのが目的の場合は、マイニングソフトウェアをインストールして使えばよいので、Coinhiveを経由するメリットは無いと思われます。（それは承知の上で別の興味からの質問と思いますが念の為）

Comment: はい知っています　thanks

Comment: @sdyjsdrtjrt さん、一般的にこのような質問サイトにおいて即座に明確な回答がくることは珍しいです。回答を作るには時間がかかりますし、回答者には回答者の仕事があって忙しいからです。良い回答を得るには幾らかの辛抱強さが必要です。もどかしいかと思いますが、数日程度待ってみるくらいの気持ちでお考えくださいませ。より詳しくは[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)などをご参照ください。

Comment: わかりましたL,m sorry

Answer (score 2):

技術的には可能かもしれませんが、利用規約に違反していそうです。

まず、authedmine.min.js の冒頭には次のように書かれています。

```
// Sadly, this source had to be obfuscated because antiviruses will detect any
// miner as a "threat" :/
```

つまり、難読化されています。このプログラムだけから挙動を調べるためには、まず難読化を解除しなければいけません (deobfuscation)。

CoinHive / AuthedMine がオープンソースであれば minify される前の authedmine.js を読めば良いのですが、簡単に調べたところ AuthedMine の元のソースコードは公開されていないようです。

というわけで難読化解除をする必要があります。ただし前提として、難読化解除という行為自体が勧められない場合があることを念頭においてください。コードをわざわざ読みにくくするということは、何かしら読みにくくしたかった理由があるということです。その理由を踏まえると難読化解除がモラルに反する場合があります。今回の場合ソースコードには「アンチウイルスソフトの誤検出対策のため」と書かれていますが、他の理由もあるかもしれません。実際 CoinHive の[利用規約 (Terms of Service)](https://coinhive.com/info/terms-of-service) には 2018 年 10 月現在以下のように書かれています。

> 2. You must not reverse engineer, hack, exploit or otherwise attack Coinhive or Coinhive's servers.
>
> (和訳: リバースエンジニアリングやハッキング、エクスプロイト、および Coinhive や Coinhive のサーバーを攻撃するようなその他の手段をとることを禁止します。)

したがって、私だったら今回の事例に関して難読化解除をすることを諦めます。一応念の為、CoinHive 側にソースコードを問い合わせても良いかもしれません。

さて、そもそも今回は、CoinHive が提供するスクリプトの代わりにハッシュを計算して、その結果を CoinHive に送りたいということでした。まず [mjy さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49435/%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E7%B5%84%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6#comment51450_49435)にあるように、元となっているコインのハッシュ計算アルゴリズム自体はオリジナルのマイニングソフトウェアについているはずなので、そちらを参考にすれば良いです。ただ計算したハッシュを CoinHive に送る部分については現状の CoinHive [HTTP API](https://coinhive.com/documentation/http-api) に含まれていないので、そこで行き詰まります。利用規約に従う限り、今回のような CoinHive の利用は難しいと私は考えます。

**補足**：質問者さんの目的によっては、CoinHive 以外の JavaScript 製マイナーで、オープンソースなものを検討することは有用かもしれません。["Cryptocurrency miner in JavaScript (alternative to CoinHive)"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46662/41046) にいくらかまとめられていますのでご覧ください。

Comment: thakyou https://github.com/thorsteinson/bitcoin-miner/blob/master/js/sha256.js これがそのアルゴリズムでしょうか　ハッシュ計算できたとしてその結果をマイニングプールに送信すれば仮想通貨がもらえる？　どうやってマイニングプールと通信するのでしょうか？イメージとしてはマイニングプール？に自分の仮想通貨のアドレス書いてhttpリクエスト出すとなんか計算式みたいのが渡されてそれでハッシュ計算して送り返すと仮想通貨がいくらか振り込まれる？？この辺詳しく教えてもらえませんでしょうか？

Comment: ただ計算したハッシュを CoinHive に送る部分については現状の CoinHive HTTP API に含まれていない>>                      計算結果をなんかしらの変数に代入してxhrかなんかで送信してそうだからその変数見つけてlocation.href=javascript:kekka=data;みたいにjsの変数にダイレクトにアクセスして代入？????????　ブラウザで動いてる関数の計算内容表示する拡張機能か何かありましたっけ

Comment: @sdyjsdrtjrt さん、その「変数を見つける」という時点でリバースエンジニアリングにあたるのではないかと思います。

Comment: 仮想通貨採掘で報酬が支払われる仕組みを教えてください


どこかのサーバーに自分の仮想通貨アドレスを載せて
http://saikutu.com/index.php?yourKASOUtuukaAddres=3xtJTJuy67kgyjk

みたいにhttpリクエスト送るとhash計算式みたいなのが送り返されてきて
次にその計算結果と自分の仮想通貨アドレスとセッションコードみたいなものを載せてhttpリクエストをまた送信すると

自分の仮想通貨のアドレスに報酬が支払われるのでしょうか？

具体的なサーバーのurlはあるのでしょうか？

追記
｛｛｛｛
処理能力を提供してくれたユーザにマイニング報酬として新規発行される仮想通貨が支払われるのです。

｛｛｛｛

できれば上のような物語的説明ではなく
具体的にどこのサーバーと通信してどんなhttpリクエスト帰ってきてどうやってマイニング(hash計算)の計算結果を
送信しているかなどの技術的説明をおねがいします！

Comment: @sdyjsdrtjrt それは元々のご質問の趣旨からはやや遠いので、別の質問として投稿して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 質問なんかブロックされててできないのです、、

Comment: 熱血さんどうか、、、、、、、、、、

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/153085

Comment: @sdyjsdrtjrt  さん、おそらく数時間前になさっていた複数の投稿がネガティブな印象を与えて一時的にブロックされたのだと思います。今は解除されているように見えます :)

Answer (score 2):

> 実際にハッシュを計算しているcryptnightのアルゴリズムは
>   coinhiveサーバーから読み込まれたjsファイルのどこに含まれているのでしょうか

CoinhiveのJavaScript内には、[WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts) のバイナリコードが含まれています。このWebAssemblyはいくつかの関数を提供し、恐らくその中の`_cryptonight_hash_variant_2` が繰り返し呼ばれるメインの処理です。

では、WebAssemblyがJavaScriptのコードのどこにあるかというと、冒頭の箇所

```
(new Function((function(s){var d={},a=(s+"").split(""), /*略*/ atob("dmFyIF8w /*略*/
```

で`atob`関数に渡されている長い文字列の中です。これはデコードされると下のようなJavaScriptコードとなり、`Function` に渡されて実行されます。

```
var _0xb10b = [
  "wss://ws024.authedmine.com/proxy",
  /*略*/
  "Res",
  "\x20self.WASM_BINARY_INLINE=\x20[0,97,115,109,1,0,
  /*略*/
```

この中の `"\x20self.WASM_BINARY_INLINE=\x20[0,97,115,109,1,0,` で始まる文字列は[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Blob)にされ[Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Worker)に渡されることで、これもまた下のようなJavaScriptのコードとなりCPUの数だけ起動されたWorker内で実行されます。

```
 self.WASM_BINARY_INLINE= [0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0,1,51,9,96, /*略*/
```

この冒頭で `self.WASM_BINARY_INLINE` に代入されている配列が該当のWebAssembryです。これが[`WebAssembly.instantiate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate) によってコンパイルされ実行されます。

Comment: ありがとう。大いにこれは参考されます　あなたはcoinhiveの仕組みについての良い技術文章を持っていますか？　私たちのgoogle翻訳を使えば国の言語をそれは問いません urlでそれらは示されます

Comment: coinhiveでなくてもマイニングの計算内容の技術的文書は何かいいものはないでしょうか　私は最終的にマイニングコードをCOBOLやほかの言語で記述しなおしたいのです。そのために仕組みを知ろうとしています

Comment: @sdyjsdrtjrt 既に指摘されていますが、新たな質問は別の質問として投稿してください。
まだ投稿がブロックされているのでしたら、過去の投稿を見直して、評価の低い物を改善するか削除する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ハッシュの計算に興味があるのなら、CoinhiveではなくMoneroのソースコードを参照されてはいかがですか。 - https://github.com/monero-project/monero